# PHP variable not working in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
echo $date1u
```

Gives me 2010-04-21

When I take that date and hardcode it into an SQL query it works fine

```
SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '2010-04-21'
```

But when I instead use the $date1u directly it doesn't work at all.

```
"SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '".$date1u."' "
```

What is the problem with my variable $date1u or SQL format that is stopping this from working?

*EDIT*

Followed a suggestion and tried

```
$result1 = "SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '".$date1u."' ";
echo $result1;
```

To see the result and some how in this situation the out put is

```
 SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '2010-04-22'
```

Some how when I echo $date1u alone its 2010-04-21 but when I echo the var in the SQL query 1 day got added

Comment: Have you assigned the above query to a variable and echoed the results?

Comment: Doesn't work how? What error do you get? Is it possible that you have some invisible character?

Comment: It doesn't work as in with example 1 I get results but with example 2 I get no results.

Comment: clean ' and ", do you test this way?

Comment: As mentioned by @BrianWarshaw assign the query to a variable and post the echo.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Yes the query is assigned to a variable and echoed out, otherwise how would example 1 work? Example 1 works in every way it should and when I echo out $date1u it is 2010-04-21.

Comment: No, we mean assign the last query you have in your example to a variable and print it out to see if it matches the hard-coded query.

Comment: When I do that I get... SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '2010-04-22'

Comment: Which is a problem because the saledate should be 2010-04-21

Comment: Ok, how are you setting $date1u? Because the problem isn't using a variable in a query, it looks like your variable just doesn't have the value you expect.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw yes that was the case. Felt like an idiot once I realized that, couldn't delete the question so I marked the answer which led me to realize the problem.

Comment: If you'd rather have it deleted, perhaps reach out to a moderator and they can whack it for you.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I've flagged it and wrote a message for mod. Feel free to second the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any whitespace either side of the variable - i.e. spaces or tabs?  If so, this is probably whats causing the problem.

Try `echo ">>" . $date1u . "<<";`

If you get ">> 2010-04-21<<" you'll know you have a leading space.  Getting the variable length may also help pinpoint problems.

Comment: Are you getting any error code back from php/mysql?

Comment: Actually that solved my problem because var was 1 day off

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if the value returned by `$date1u` is returning a value surrounded by quotes. If so, you need to remove the quotes before plugging it in your SQL query.

Comment: have updated answer because ' ' are not in what is echoed out.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing

this:

```
SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '2010-04-21'
```

should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = 2010-04-21
```

you need to take out the `''` on the date. This is for sql query error.

Comment: SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '2010-04-21' works fine. Its the version with $date1u that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my server and it worked.

```
"SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn='OSI' AND saledate='$date1u'"
```

It may not be perfect programming but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT * FROM phoneappdetail WHERE salebarn = 'OSI' AND saledate = '" . trim($date1u) . "'"
```